# Error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Android

Tags: android, gradle

I am following this [tutorial to create swipe tabs](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/). But I get the above error.

My gradle dependencies sturucture

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```

Here are my files. `MainActivity.java`

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1")); //this line gives error
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2")); //this line gives error
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    PageAdapter pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
 }

}
```

And my `PageAdapter.java` file is

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

  public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new InstaPicSwipeTab();
        case 1:
            return new SongsDownloadSwipeTab();
    }
    return null;
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
    return 2;
 }
}
```

And this is what LogCat is giving me

```
12-08 00:27:24.452 11770-11770/com.example.suraj.freewee E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.suraj.freewee, PID: 11770
                                                                           java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/TintManager;
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.<init>(TabLayout.java:1041)
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:582)
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTabView(TabLayout.java:616)
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:334)
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:309)
                                                                               at com.example.suraj.freewee.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.suraj.freewee-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.suraj.freewee-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.<init>(TabLayout.java:1041) 
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:582) 
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTabView(TabLayout.java:616) 
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:334) 
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:309) 
                                                                               at com.example.suraj.freewee.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23) 
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                            Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager
                                                                               at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                    ... 19 more
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: what is your gradle dependency section looking like?

Comment: @inner_class7 question updated

Comment: @sap are you solved problem?

Answer (score 24):

The version of support library and design library should be the same.

I changed my

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

and issue fixed for me.

**Note**: my compileSdkVersion and buildToolVersion is below
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

Comment: I can confirm that there's a problem with appcompat-v7:23.1.1 resulting in runtime exception `NoClassDefFoundError Failed resolution of TintManager`. I updated to `23.3.0` and the exception was fixed

Answer (score 19):

this comes up when a class exists at compile time but not at runtime, right click on the `app` go to `open module settings` select `dependencies` click on the `+` and select 'library dependency' select `design` and click `ok`, wait for gradle to run, re-run your app, am sure that will fix it.

your top level gradle will need to look like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "aubry.chromio.com.dressup"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.java'])
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.so'])


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'

}
```

Comment: Still i have a issue

Comment: I had the same issue, turned out I was using different versions of appcompat in my modules. Make sure you use the same version of each library and it might fight your problems.

Comment: solution: don't use `appcompat-v7:23.1.1` - it's bugged

Answer (score 3):

You must have to import same appcompat and design libraries and also 12.2.0 version.

> I fix it by importing these libraries.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add this: 
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' or high version :
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0' is nice.

support:design has contained support:appcompat.