# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/TintManager;

Tags: android, github

I found some answers but none of them fit my problem.
When I add these things to my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'

    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
}
```

everything works fine, but when I add this :

```
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.5'
```

app crashes and shows this error.
I try to use code from github.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34141152/error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android

Comment: [That library is pulling in `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0`](https://bintray.com/artifact/download/81813780/maven/com/wang/avi/library/1.0.5/library-1.0.5.pom). Since there are other bug fixes in the support libraries, I suggest you move all your dependencies from `23.0.1` to `23.2.0`, and see if this clears up your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.5'` depends on `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'`. There are some internal differences between 23.2.0 and prior versions (one of which you currently depend on.

The newest version of support library is 23.3.0 which should be compatible.

If it doesn't work out I can recommend 23.2.1 instead of 23.2.0.

Don't forget to update all your support library versions:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0' // includes appcompat-v7 which includes support-v4
  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'

  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'

  compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
}
```